# shrQATest.h in cuda sample

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I am compiling vectorAdd.cu (from cuda samples) in Visual Studio 2010. Where I got a error

> shrQATest.h is not found.

I searched for the header file in Nvidia include folder(C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include), but I didn't find it.

My question is, does shrQATest.h come with the Nvidia toolkit or do I have to install it manually?

Comment: If you are getting this then it sounds like you are not building the project properly.  You have to load the included visual studio projects, which will set the proper include directories and include dependent library projects.  Are you trying to compile vectorAdd.cu in isolation rather than in its vcproj?

Comment: you means cuda samples from toolkit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this file in *C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\shared\inc*, maybe same directory exist on cuda 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I found shrQATest.h in C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\shared\inc

and I added it in include libraries..but still I have errors in program for this line..

int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

blockDim, blockIdx and threadIdx are not defined..Do you have any idea for which header these are releated..

Comment: blockIdx, threadIdx are defined in device_launch_parameters.h file, but they use uint3 struct, which defined in vector_types.h header file. Check availability for both of them.

Comment: Thanks again, do you have any idea about ../common/book.h in "CUDA -By Example" book. Actually I am following this book to start compiling cuda basic programs, but unfortunately in book they didn't mention about "../common/book.h".They gave a link but it is not working, because of nvidia site is blocked for some hacking reasons.

Comment: You can download the files for "CUDA by Example" at the link below. The file book.h is in the "common" directory. http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/cuda_by_example.zip